# TCP listener that drops all of its input?

Tags: socat

I'm trying to implement a TCP listener that accepts connections and then simply drops all of its input (it's for a test harness).

Right now, I'm using `socat - tcp-listen:2003,fork,reuseaddr`, but that prints the input to stdout. I don't want that.

I can't redirect the output to `/dev/null`, because I'm doing this in the [alpine/socat docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/socat/), and it's not actually using a shell, so redirection doesn't work.

If I try to use `socat /dev/null tcp-listen:2003,fork,reuseaddr`, then any connection is dropped immediately, presumably because `socat` can't read from `/dev/null`.

What's the best way to implement a TCP listener that simply drops everything on the floor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
socat /dev/null,ignoreeof tcp-listen:2003,fork,reuseaddr
```

Comment: I tried `ignoreeof` ... on the wrong address.

Answer (score 1):

Best is a tricky criterion, but one can observe that Docker is as necessary for this as Microsoft Excel is.  ☺

We already know a Unix program that reads its input until EOF and effectively discards it:

```
cat > /dev/null
```

Turning this into a TCP server is a very simple exercise.  *It is what UCSPI-TCP is all about.*  It takes programs that use standard I/O and wraps a simple framework around them that makes them into TCP servers.  One can substitute something else for `cat` and change the service protocol without having to worry about the transport.  One can similarly substitute UCSPI-LOCAL tools for UCSPI-TCP tools, and change the transport, without having to do a thing to `cat`.

There are several UCSPI-TCP toolsets.  Daniel J. Bernstein wrote one.  Laurent Bercot wrote one.  Gerrit Pape wrote one.  Adam Sampson wrote one.  I wrote one.  Moreover, one can mix and match tools from multiple toolsets, this stuff being intentionally readily composable.  One can use my `fdredir` or Laurent Bercot's `redirfd`, or even spawn a non-interactive `sh`.  (The former two have a lower overhead than a full-blown `sh`, and for the nosh tools `fdredir` is even a built-in so it further avoids the overhead of chaining through an external command.)

So there are several ways of doing this:

1. Bernstein `tcpserver` (original or djbwares; no IPv6 support)

   1. `tcpserver -R -H -l 0 0.0.0.0 2003 fdredir --write 1 /dev/null cat`
   2. `tcpserver -R -H -l 0 0.0.0.0 2003 redirfd -w 1 /dev/null cat`
   3. `tcpserver -R -H -l 0 0.0.0.0 2003 sh -c 'exec > /dev/null cat'`
2. Hoffman `tcpserver` (does both IPv4 and IPv6; has original Bernstein defaults for DNS and INFO lookups that need to be turned off)

   1. `tcpserver -R -H -l 0 ::0 2003 fdredir --write 1 /dev/null cat`
   2. `tcpserver -R -H -l 0 ::0 2003 redirfd -w 1 /dev/null cat`
   3. `tcpserver -R -H -l 0 ::0 2003 sh -c 'exec > /dev/null cat'`
3. my `tcpserver` shim (does both IPv4 and IPv6 but has to run separate instances for each; has more modern defaults)

   1. `tcpserver ::0 2003 fdredir --write 1 /dev/null cat`
   2. `tcpserver ::0 2003 redirfd -w 1 /dev/null cat`
   3. `tcpserver ::0 2003 sh -c 'exec > /dev/null cat'`
4. my UCSPI-TCP tools (does both IPv4 and IPv6, in one on Linux and FreeBSD)

   1. `tcp-socket-listen --combine4and6 ::0 2003 tcp-socket-accept fdredir --write 1 /dev/null cat`
   2. `tcp-socket-listen --combine4and6 ::0 2003 tcp-socket-accept redirfd -w 1 /dev/null cat`
   3. `tcp-socket-listen --combine4and6 ::0 2003 tcp-socket-accept sh -c 'exec > /dev/null cat'`
5. Bercot `s6-tcpserver6` (substitute `s6-tcpserver4` for IPv4)

   1. `s6-tcpserver6 ::0 2003 fdredir --write 1 /dev/null cat`
   2. `s6-tcpserver6 ::0 2003 redirfd -w 1 /dev/null cat`
   3. `s6-tcpserver6 ::0 2003 sh -c 'exec > /dev/null cat'`
6. Bercot s6-networking tools  (substitute `s6-tcpserver4` for IPv4)

   1. `s6-tcpserver6-socketbinder -B ::0 2003 s6-tcpserver6d fdredir --write 1 /dev/null cat`
   2. `s6-tcpserver6-socketbinder -B ::0 2003 s6-tcpserver6d redirfd -w  1 /dev/null cat`
   3. `s6-tcpserver6-socketbinder -B ::0 2003 s6-tcpserver6d sh -c 'exec > /dev/null cat'`
7. Pape `tcpsvd` (no IPv6 support)

   1. `tcpsvd 0.0.0.0 2003 fdredir --write 1 /dev/null cat`
   2. `tcpsvd 0.0.0.0 2003 redirfd -w  1 /dev/null cat`
   3. `tcpsvd 0.0.0.0 2003 sh -c 'exec > /dev/null cat'`
8. Sampson `onenetd` (does both IPv4 and IPv6 but has to run separate instances for each)

   1. `onenetd -6 ::0 2003 fdredir --write 1 /dev/null cat`
   2. `onenetd -6 ::0 2003 redirfd -w  1 /dev/null cat`
   3. `onenetd -6 ::0 2003 sh -c 'exec > /dev/null cat'`

Enjoy substituting

```
hexdump -C 1>&2
```

or (without `sh`)

```
fdmove -c 1 2 hexdump -C
```

for the server program so that you get a local log of what your client program under test is doing.  ☺

## Further reading

- Protocol:

  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[The gen on the UNIX Client-Server Program Interface](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/UCSPI.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.
  - Daniel J. Bernstein (1996). *[UNIX Client-Server Program Interface](http://cr.yp.to/proto/ucspi.txt)*.  cr.yp.to.
- toolsets:

  - Daniel J. Bernstein. *[ucspi-tcp](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp.html)*.  cr.yp.to.
  - [s6-networking](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/index.html).  Laurent Bercot.  skarnet.org.
  - [execline](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/index.html).  Laurent Bercot.  skarnet.org.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). *[nosh](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/).*  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). *[djbwares](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/).*  Softwares.
  - [ipsvd](http://smarden.org/ipsvd/index.html).  Gerrit Pape.  smarden.org.
  - [onenetd](http://offog.org/code/onenetd/).  Adam Sampson.  offog.org.
- reference manuals:

  - Daniel J. Bernstein. *[The `tcpserver` program](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html)*.  ucspi-tcp.
  - Erwin Hoffmann.  [`tcpserver`](http://fehcom.de/ipnet/ucspi-tcp6/tcpserver.html).  *ucspi-tcp6*.  fehcom.de.
  - [`s6-tcpserver4`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpserver4.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *s6-networking*.  skarnet.org.
  - [`s6-tcpserver6`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpserver6.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *s6-networking*.  skarnet.org.
  - [`fdmove`](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/fdmove.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *execline*.  skarnet.org.
  - [`redirfd`](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/redirfd.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *execline*.  skarnet.org.
  - [`tcpsvd`](http://smarden.org/ipsvd/tcpsvd.8.html).  *ipsvd*.  Gerrit Pape.  smarden.org.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`tcpserver`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/guide/commands/tcpserver.xml).  *djbwares*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`fdredir`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/fdredir.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`fdmove`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/fdmove.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`tcp-socket-listen`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/tcp-socket-listen.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`tcp-socket-accept`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/tcp-socket-accept.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`tcpserver`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/tcpserver.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

Comment: It's in docker because the rest of the system test harness is in docker.